# Composite foreign key updation failed

Tags: mysql, sql

I am facing the issue in composite foreign key.

I have tried example, and tried with structure change too but still i am not succeed. I have trid in mysql server.

```
CREATE TABLE `parenttable` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `parenttable` (`ID`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 1),
(3, 1);
ALTER TABLE `parenttable`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ADD KEY `ID` (`ID`,`status`);

ALTER TABLE `parenttable`
  MODIFY `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
COMMIT;


CREATE TABLE `parenttable2` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `parenttable2` (`ID`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 1),
(3, 1);

ALTER TABLE `parenttable2`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ADD KEY `ID` (`ID`,`status`);

ALTER TABLE `parenttable2`
  MODIFY `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
COMMIT;


CREATE TABLE `childtable` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `childtable` (`ID`, `parent_id`, `parent_id2`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 1),
(3, 1, 1, 1),
(4, 2, 2, 1),
(5, 2, 3, 1),
(6, 1, 1, 1);


ALTER TABLE `childtable`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ADD KEY `fk_childTable_parent_id` (`parent_id`,`status`),
  ADD KEY `fk_childTable_parent_id2` (`parent_id2`,`status`);
ALTER TABLE `childtable`
  MODIFY `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=7;


ALTER TABLE `childtable`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_childTable_parent_id` FOREIGN KEY         
 (`parent_id`,`status`) REFERENCES `parenttable` (`ID`, `status`) ON DELETE     
 CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_childTable_parent_id2` FOREIGN KEY 
(`parent_id2`,`status`) REFERENCES `parenttable2` (`ID`, `status`) ON DELETE 
CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
COMMIT;
```

I want to update all child rows "status" when parent is changed and single child "status" row too.

Please give me suggestion. Thank You.

Comment: I have looked into this but i could not format the post. Thanks Ryan.

Comment: Can you please show the update statement you're trying to execute?

Comment: I have just update field of parent2 table status. but i cant change the status of child table and i am getting error.

Comment: @NevilleKuyt I am facing an error foreign key updation. I got the issue when i am trying to update status column for parent table 2 this throws an error for table 1(parenttable). I assume status column is same for both(parenttable and parenttable2) so It will not work. Could you please suggestion me any other option? Btw Thanks for your reply.